# Changing grid size in tikz-timing package

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids, tikz-timing

The grind in the figure contain a grid of 2x8 squeezers (2 rows and 8 columns) and I use 4 elements.

[image: Example]

How could I tell `tikz-timing` to use a grid of 1x4 squeezers?

Below is an example of my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary{nicetabs}  

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikztimingtable}
   & 4L\\ 
   & 4H\\ 
   & CCCC \\ 
   & [C]CCCC \\
   & 2{2C} \\
   \extracode
   \tablegrid[black!25]
 \end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you have an error in your example. The ``&    12{2C} C \\`` line is ignored with a warning raised. You miss a ``\\`` in the line above. Also code lines 3-5 are not really required for this example. Example should usually be as minimal as possible.

Comment: you are right, i removed it at my new example, below `edit`

Comment: Your update is a completely new question (like "How to use tikz-timing together with the external library") and has nothing to do with the grid. I suggest removing this part again and post it as a fresh question of its own. You can link back to this question if you want, but it isn't really required in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\tablegrid` uses the `grid` command of TikZ, which is controlled by the `step` setting. There is also `xstep` and `ystep` if you want to set the grid step size different for each axis. In your case you want to set `step=1`. The default is `step=.5`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikztiminglibrary{nicetabs} 

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikztimingtable}
   & 4L\\ 
   & 4H\\ 
   & CCCC \\ 
   & [C]CCCC \\
   \extracode
   \tablegrid[black!25,step=1]
 \end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]